# Combinatorics solution verification

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

**In the Superenalotto game you have to guess 6 distinct numbers chosen from
number 1 and number 90. How many sets of six numbers can be formed?** $90 \choose 6$

**By extracting 7 cards from a classic deck of 40 cards (4 suits, 10 cards for each
suit), how many possible draws that contain 3 aces?** $4 \choose 3$ $\cdot \ 36 \cdot 32 \cdot 28 \cdot 24$, because I'm choosing 3 aces from 4, then I'm counting the number of cards that remains, so $AAXYZJ$:
$$\mathbf{AA : } {4 \choose 3} \\ \mathbf{X: } \ 36 \  (left \ choices) \\ \mathbf{Y: } \ 32 \\ \mathbf{Z: } \ 28 \\ \mathbf{Z: } \ 24$$
so $4 \choose 3$ $\cdot \ 36 \cdot 32 \cdot 28 \cdot 24$

**I have a tennis tournament with 64 players, each match is played 1vs1, how many matches are played until the end of the tournament?** if I'm not wrong, by counting by hand they should be 56 (I found it by divide by 8, count manually with a scheme disputed matches, and then multiply the result by 8), but I can't find this result with combinatorics. I think I need to do $64 \choose 2$ to count all possible matches and then subtract or divide for something that I can't get

Comment: For the second, if there are $4$ aces in the deck, it should be ${4 \choose 3} \cdot {36 \choose 4}$.

Comment: For the third, I do not understand the language and how the games are being played.

Comment: +1 to your query for showing good work.  There are two reasons why the comment of @MathLover is correct [1] You assumed that you could not have 2 non-Aces that were the same rank.  This means that you wrongly assumed that you could not have 2 deuces. [2] Suppose the problem was changed so that the other 4 cards must be different ranks.  Your answer would still be wrong, because of overcounting.  Under this altered problem, the correct enumeration would be $$\binom{4}{3} \times \binom{9}{4} \times (4^4).$$
...see next comment

Comment: The $\binom{9}{4}$ factor refers to the number of distinct
ways of selecting 4 ranks from $\{2,3,\cdots, 10\}.$
The $(4^4)$ factor refers to the number of ways of drawing
a specific card from each of the 4 ranks.  Overcounting refers to (for example), the case where the 1st non-Ace card drawn was 
the $2_s$ and the 2nd non_Ace card drawn was the $3_s$ would also
be counted when the 1st non-Ace card drawn was 
the $3_s$ and the 2nd non_Ace card drawn was the $2_s$.
Note that you are required to presume that the order that the cards
are drawn is not relevant.

Comment: I agree with cyclowolf's answer for the tennis match question.  Note that it can alternatively be computed as $(2^5) + (2^4) + (2^3) + (2^2) + (2^1) + 1.$  The idea is that in a specific round that involves $(2^n)$ players, there must be $[2^{(n-1)}]$ matches in that specific round.

Comment: @MathLover I edited the third question, which I hope now is more clear.

Comment: If it is by elimination, there are $2^5+2^4+2^3+2^2+2^1+1 = 63$ matches in total as @user2661923 mentioned. But somehow the question is still not clear - may be it is asking in how many ways we can set up the tournament with given players. Is it translated from another language?

Comment: I agree with @MathLover's last comment.  It is possible that the mathSE reviewers (including me) are misinterpreting your intent in the tennis match question.  In particular, the following excerpt is inconsistent with our interpretation: "I think I need to do $64 \choose 2$ to count all possible matches".

Comment: I understand all the answers thanks for the help you all, anyway, the third question is translated from Italian @MathLover, I want to make it clear in case someone who asks about my own problems may find this question helpful. it asks "I have a tennis tournament with 64 players, each match is played 1vs1 how many matches are played until the end of the tournament?" if now is understandable I'm going to edit the question another time, if is not please suggest me. :-)

Comment: Good clarification - your last comment is **unambiguous**.  It makes it clear what the intent of the question is, and indicates that the interpretation of the mathSE reviewers is consistent with your intent.

Comment: yes more clear:) pls edit it. I have a tennis tournament with 64 players, each match is played 1vs1 and winner moves to the next round...

Comment: @user2661923 that because I was thinking I need to do inclusion-exclusion, but it's just my attempt nothing more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First one is correct.

Where are you getting the numbers for the second question, specifically the part that is displayed? We choose three of the four aces, and after that there are 36 non-aces, of which we need four. What expression does this leave us with? The answer should be $\tbinom{4}{3}\tbinom{36}{4}$.

And for the third, notice how one player is removed from the tournament every match. You want there to be one player remaining, so how many matches must be played? This is equivalent to removing 63 players, so 63 matches must be played.

Comment: sorry there was a typo on the second answer, by the way for AA so the two aces of the hand, I'm choosing 3 aces from 4, then for x I olny have 36 cards left  (40-4) the same for 32 (36-4) and for 28 and 24. is that right?

Comment: there are 32 matches for the third question right?

Comment: Why are you subtracting 4 every time you choose one non-ace card for your hand? You can have two non-ace cards of the same rank.

Comment: because I'm thinking "I have another empty space to put a card, I have * choices to pick a card, and because the suits are 4 I'm subtracting 4 every time from the possible choices", but as mathlover and user2661923 shown in the chat I was wrong. so nevermind, thanks for the answer.